# How virtual ads work in stadiums?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, video, artificial-intelligence

I was looking at a technology which enables virtual advertisement on the perimeter ads in soccer. It's relatively an old technology for a few years back, but I'm surprised to see the quality of it. They overlay the physical perimeter ads with new ads on different camera feeds. Basically from [this link.](https://www.adi.tv/sales/markets/sport) And here is a video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HreDhkq4gk&feature=emb_title).

*LED perimeter system with integrated virtual replacement technology - makes it possible to change the content seen by different viewing audiences around the world*

**How does this overlaying mechanism work?** Is there any hardware involved (like the LED boards itself), or it is purely based on Computer Vision and Augmented Reality? How can it be such high-quality without glitches purely based on computer vision?!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since "green grass" and "viewers/whatevers behind the LED boards" do nicely contrast from the boards themselves, and because the shape of these is pretty precise known beforehand, I'd probably go with "pure computer vision". You could even make the image processing aware of what's displayed on the LEDs, so that recognition gets even easier.

Of course you could do something like blinking the LEDs at a specific rate and synchronize cameras to that blinking, so that it gets even easier on the processing side, but honestly, I don't think that's necessary. Might still be done to make the whole thing failsafer.

Comment: Ummm, interesting thing is that they also know if it has occlusion like smoke or players, and it is still pretty glitch-free :-/

Comment: Well, if you know what you're expecting (namely, the ad that your own system displays on the banners), then finding the occlusion isn't that hard.

Comment: Do you know a good reference with sample codes how to do that?

Comment: Sadly, I don't. Sorry.